# Beamer with Biblatex: adjustwidth in block breaks indentation of bibliography

Tags: beamer, biblatex, posters, adjustwidth

I am using beamer with biblatex to create a bibliography and have redefined the "block" in my template. In order to get some padding inside the block I am using the adjustwidth command.
When putting my bibliography in a block without added padding (i.e. without adjustwidth) then the first line of each bib entry starts at the very left and the subsequent lines of that entry are indented.

When adding the adjustwidth command, however, this behaviour is broken and each element after the first one is fully indented (including the first line) which makes the bibliography hard to read and also looks inconsistent.

[image: Broken Bibliography Example]

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me with keeping the indentation correct while still having padding in the block.

Here's a minimum working example showcasing the behaviour:

Tex file:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\RequirePackage{exscale}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

% Block
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex,dp=2ex,center]{block title}
    \vskip0pt
    \begin{adjustwidth}{1ex}{1ex}
    \centering
    \usebeamerfont{block title}\insertblocktitle
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \vskip-1.25ex
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=0.025ex]{block separator}\end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  {\parskip0pt\par}
  \usebeamerfont{block body}
  \vskip-0.5ex
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=0ex]{block body}
  \justifying
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1ex}{1ex}
  \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
  \vskip-2ex
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}
{
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt
  \vspace*{2ex}
}

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\paperwidth}
This is a test \autocite{AndersonStrongMixedintegerProgramming2020} and \autocite{AndersonStrongMixedintegerProgramming2021}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\paperwidth}
\begin{block}
\printbibliography
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the bib file:

```
@article{AndersonStrongMixedintegerProgramming2020,
  title = {Strong Mixed-Integer Programming Formulations for Trained Neural Networks},
  author = {Anderson, Ross and Huchette, Joey and Ma, Will and Tjandraatmadja, Christian and Vielma, Juan Pablo},
  date = {2020-09-01},
  journaltitle = {Mathematical Programming},
  shortjournal = {Math. Program.},
  volume = {183},
  number = {1},
  pages = {3--39},
  issn = {1436-4646},
  doi = {10/gnbscf},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s10107-020-01474-5},
  urldate = {2021-11-04},
  langid = {english}
}

@article{AndersonStrongMixedintegerProgramming2021,
  title = {Strong Mixed-Integer Programming Formulations for Trained Neural Networks 2},
  author = {Andersons, Ross and Huchette, Joey and Ma, Will and Tjandraatmadja, Christian and Vielma, Juan Pablo},
  date = {2020-09-01},
  journaltitle = {Mathematical Programming},
  shortjournal = {Math. Program.},
  volume = {183},
  number = {1},
  pages = {3--39},
  issn = {1436-4646},
  doi = {10/gnbscf},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s10107-020-01474-5},
  urldate = {2021-11-04},
  langid = {english}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the margins inside of blocks, I would either use the `left-/rightskip` or the `sep` option of the `beamercolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{orchid}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\RequirePackage{exscale}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
%\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,center]{block title}
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode,leftskip=1cm,rightskip=1cm]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}  
{\end{beamercolorbox}\vskip\smallskipamount}

\title{Some title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{title}
\lipsum
\end{block}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.4\paperwidth}
This is a test \autocite{knuth:ct} and \autocite{westfahl:space}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.4\paperwidth}
\begin{block}{}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth-2cm}
\printbibliography
\end{minipage}
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]